Windows fatal exception: access violation with os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] after updating Spyder IDE
I've been running pyspark scripts for around a year with Anaconda distribution and Spyder 5.5.4.  It took a while to get pyspark running so I left my pyspark environment as it was.  The pyspark environment was cloned from my base environment then added to.  When Spyder moved to version 6, I decided to update it to 6.0.2 in pyspark environment.  I had problems with my scripts so I reverted back to 5.5.4.  BUT scripts now fail to run.
I narrowed the problem down to path variable (I think!) but am now stuck!
Running Spyder 5.5.4 from my 'base' environment, the test script below runs OK with output:
['C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\jmbar\.spyder-py3']
When I run the same script in Spyder 5.5.4 from my Pyspark environment, it fails (see below)
import os
user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
print(user_paths)

With Spyder 5.5.4 from my Pyspark environment I get:
'Windows fatal exception: access violation' with the following info and kernel restarts:
"Main thread:
Thread 0x00004cdc (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 204 in wait_until
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 743 in cmd_input
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 691 in cmdloop
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 665 in _cmdloop
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 344 in interaction
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\pdb.py", line 243 in user_call
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\bdb.py", line 136 in dispatch_call
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\bdb.py", line 92 in trace_dispatch
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\os.py", line 675 in getitem
File "d:\2computing\python_jb\python_howto_jbpc\howto-files-system\view_pythonpath.py", line 14 in 
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\bdb.py", line 598 in run
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 912 in run
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 473 in exec_code
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 615 in _exec_file
File "C:\Users\jmbar\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 660 in debugfile
File "C:\Users\jmbar\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4692\3001907695.py", line 1 in 
Restarting kernel...
"
I'm running Windows 11 PC
I don't want to have to delete the pyspark environment then relive the hassle to get it working again.  I'm baffled why a simple IDE update should cause such problems.
Any help gratefully received.

For info if anybody else has similar problem.  I gave up trying to fix the problem.  I made copies of my environments then uninstalled Anaconda and deleted cache folders (in Windows EXplorer).
Then clean install of fresh download of Anaconda.  This ran OK (note the latest download has Spyder 5.5.1- not the later versions I'd been running).    I then copied my old environments in to the active 'envs' folder - but needed to add some of the packages again (pyspark, delta-spark) but it all seems to work now.  Moral of this for me is DO NOT UPDATE Spyder unless I really have to!
